# How to implement API versioning with Node.js, Express, and Swagger?

Tags: node.js, express, backend, versioning

I have a backend application built with Node.js and Express, and I'm using Swagger for API documentation.
Currently, I have two versions of my API: v1 and v2. I'm facing difficulties in implementing API versioning, particularly in structuring my file system.

Initially, with v1, my file system looked like this:

```
routes:
  - users
    - index.ts
    - docs.ts
  - books
    - index.ts
    - docs.ts
  - magazines
    - index.ts
    - docs.ts
```

Now, with the introduction of v2, I'm unsure about the optimal file system structure. One possibility I'm considering is:

```
routes:
  v1:
    - users
      - index.ts
      - docs.ts
    - books
      - index.ts
      - docs.ts
    - magazines
      - index.ts
      - docs.ts
  v2:
    - users
      - index.ts
      - docs.ts
```

I have a couple of problems that I need assistance with:

1. How should I structure the Swagger documentation to accommodate v1 and v2 versions?
   Should I have separate sections for each version, and place the relevant routes under each section?
2. In the backend, how can I determine the latest version for a specific route?
   Currently, I have to manually search for the latest version, which is not convenient.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to implement API versioning in this scenario, ensuring an efficient file system structure and a convenient approach to determine the latest version for each route.

Comment: I would personally handle this in git branches. Then for deployment run one server for each API and use an API gateway to route requests to the right server. Node processes are cheap and don't use much CPU or RAM resources so you can even run both servers on the same machine on different ports if you want to. Let the API gateway handle routing.

Comment: I never found an elegant solution to this, in the end I have done the same thing as @slebetman suggested and differentiate versions via the  URL E.g. `https://my-api.com/<version>/user/<user id>